# Why is my 6TB harddrive showing as two unallocated partitions?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

[image]

This is a new 6TB "WD Black" Western Digital drive.

I can't remove either section. I can't create a larger-than 2048GB partition.

A Windows 7 MBR was accidentially written to this drive, but has since been removed. Aside from that, it has never been used or partitioned.

How can I make one big 6TB partition? Why does it have this arbitrary internal division?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In order for an operating system to fully support storage devices that have capacities that exceed 2 terabytes (2 TB, or 2 trillion bytes), the device must be initialized by using the GUID partition table (GPT) partitioning scheme. This scheme supports addressing of the full range of storage capacity. If the user intends to start the computer from one of these large disks, the system’s base firmware interface must use the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) and not BIOS.

From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581408/windows-support-for-hard-disks-that-are-larger-than-2-tb

You'll need to reinitialize the drive with a GPT instead of an MBR.

In order to do that, right click on the grey box that says Disk 1 and select "Convert to GPT Disk".  Please note that by doing this you are erasing the partition table and by extension you are making any data on the drive difficult to recover (ie, logically erasing it).

Comment: I am pretty sure, converting the disk in this way (added by Joshua), will result in data loss.

Comment: This is true.  There are ways around it. The "smart" way around it is to record the locations of the partitions and write a GPT with that information already populated.  But it is surprisingly difficult to find a partition manager that will perform that action.

Comment: I can’t fault your answer for not providing the warning since it was not your suggestion.  I would, revert that edit, if this was my answer.

Comment: I added a warning.  Hopefully this is sufficient?

Comment: I was actually trying to indicate. that author of the question should have never edited your question.  Your answer was complete without that specific step.  Yes, The warning is fine.

Comment: The edit I provided is a perfect answer to my question. I mention that it's a new and empty drive in the question. The warning is a good one, but there's nothing wrong with the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with help of [this page](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html) (Solution 3). An edited version is as follows:

1. Open Command Prompt as an administrator and type **diskpart**.
2. Type **list disk** and press Enter. Note the disk number that represents the disk you wish to fix.
3. Type **select disk x**. x should be the disk number from step 2. (e.g. **select disk 1**)
4. Type **clean** and press Enter. This action will remove all the contents of the disk. An error may occur. You may ignore it.
5. From here on you can format your disk as you wish. (e.g. Open **Disk Management**,  right-click the unallocated space you wish to format and click **format**)

Answer (score -1):

Use a free copy of PartitionGuru from Eassos

Use the function to convert MBR partition table to GUID partition table

This function does not result in loss of data

Your previous mbr partition will be the first partition in GUID partition table